# Declare multi-array

Tags: arrays, syntax, vb6, declaration

Sorry for the rookie question, but currently if I need multi-array (Array of Arrays), I declare it as Variant:

```
Dim ma() As Variant
ReDim ma(1 To 3)
ma(1) = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

Besides it works, I wish to know is there alternative declaration. 
For example, next not work:

```
Dim mm() As Integer()
Dim mm()() As Integer
```

**P.S.** Thanks to everybody response. But I have the feeling that my question is not clear. It's not about multi-dimensional arrays, nor yet about array's size. It's about the **Type**. Yes, there is many examples for multi-arrays (Array of Arrays), but all they use `Variant`. Maybe (like ot not) that's the only way to create multi-array? That's all what I need to know.

Comment: http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_declare_arrays.html

Comment: Yes you need to use Variants, at least for the "outer array."  The advantage of using "arrays of arrays" of course is that you can have ragged arrays (sub-arrays can have varying LBound/UBound values instead of the same for all).

Comment: Try array of UDTs, if you need specific types for the "columns".

Comment: @panayot - my answer below does not use variants.

Comment: @chuex - Your suggestion is fine if the question was about multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @wqw - I'm too consider that idea, thanks (+1)

Comment: @Bob77 - I deeply hope that may exist hidden to my eye declaration, but if there no such then post this as answer.

Comment: Just to clarify, there is no array "type". You can have the intrinsic type (single elements) objects or variants. Arrays need to be in a strongly typed variable or a variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to use Variants, at least for the "outer array." The advantage of using "arrays of arrays" of course is that you can have ragged arrays (sub-arrays can have varying LBound/UBound values instead of the same for all).

Comment: you dont have to use variants. see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can specify as follows for 3-D arrays:

```
Dim ma(1 To 3, 1 To 2, 0 To 5) as Integer
Dim mb(0 To 2, 0 To 2, 0 To 2) as Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to declare about the array's size, because of the allocation in the memory.. 
when you declare it as Variant the compiler know the type and size at runtime so it doesn't gives you any error.. but when you declare it as some type.. you need to declare about the size.. look at the link I gave you in the first comment

Answer (score 0):

I found you a good example here: http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/79979-Array-of-Arrays-(VB6)

```
Dim ArrayArray() As Variant
ReDim ArrayArray(1)

Dim StringArray() As String
Dim DateArray() As Date

ReDim StringArray(2, 3)
ReDim DateArray(4, 5)

ArrayArray(0) = StringArray
ArrayArray(1) = DateArray
```

And here is a tutorial: http://visualbasic.freetutes.com/learn-vb6/arrays-of-arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

when you declare it with empty () then you can later redim it with any dimensions you want

create the following project, run it, click on the 2 command buttons, and have a look at shown data

```
'1 form with
'    2 command buttons : name=Command1, name=Command2
'    1 label : name=Label1
Option Explicit

Private mintVal() As Integer

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim intIndex1 As Integer, intIndex2 As Integer, intIndex3 As Integer
  ReDim mintVal(5, 3, 4) As Integer
  For intIndex1 = 0 To UBound(mintVal, 1)
    For intIndex2 = 0 To UBound(mintVal, 2)
      For intIndex3 = 0 To UBound(mintVal, 3)
        mintVal(intIndex1, intIndex2, intIndex3) = intIndex1 + intIndex2 + intIndex3
      Next intIndex3
    Next intIndex2
  Next intIndex1
  ShowVals3
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
  Dim intIndex1 As Integer, intIndex2 As Integer
  ReDim mintVal(3, 7) As Integer
  For intIndex1 = 0 To UBound(mintVal, 1)
    For intIndex2 = 0 To UBound(mintVal, 2)
      mintVal(intIndex1, intIndex2) = intIndex1 * intIndex2
    Next intIndex2
  Next intIndex1
  ShowVals2
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
  Dim sngWidth As Integer, sngHeight As Single
  Dim sngCmdWidth As Single, sngCmdHeight As Single
  sngWidth = ScaleWidth
  sngCmdHeight = 495
  sngCmdWidth = sngWidth / 2
  sngHeight = ScaleHeight - 495
  Label1.Move 0, 0, sngWidth, sngHeight
  Command1.Move 0, sngHeight, sngCmdWidth, sngCmdHeight
  Command2.Move sngCmdWidth, sngHeight, sngCmdWidth, sngCmdHeight
End Sub

Private Sub ShowVals2()
  Dim intIndex1 As Integer, intIndex2 As Integer
  Dim strShow As String
  strShow = ""
  For intIndex1 = 0 To UBound(mintVal, 1)
    strShow = strShow & CStr(mintVal(intIndex1, 0))
    For intIndex2 = 1 To UBound(mintVal, 2)
      strShow = strShow & "," & CStr(mintVal(intIndex1, intIndex2))
    Next intIndex2
    strShow = strShow & vbCrLf
  Next intIndex1
  Label1.Caption = strShow
End Sub

Private Sub ShowVals3()
  Dim intIndex1 As Integer, intIndex2 As Integer, intIndex3 As Integer
  Dim strShow As String
  strShow = ""
  For intIndex1 = 0 To UBound(mintVal, 1)
    For intIndex2 = 0 To UBound(mintVal, 2)
      strShow = strShow & CStr(mintVal(intIndex1, intIndex2, 0))
      For intIndex3 = 1 To UBound(mintVal, 3)
        strShow = strShow & "," & CStr(mintVal(intIndex1, intIndex2, intIndex3))
      Next intIndex3
      strShow = strShow & vbCrLf
    Next intIndex2
    strShow = strShow & vbCrLf
  Next intIndex1
  Label1.Caption = strShow
End Sub
```

Comment: This does nothing to help have "ragged" arrays though, which is probably what he was after in the question.  Arrays of arrays are entirely different from multidimensional arrays.

Comment: That is true. In that case I would create a user defined type containing the inner array (which can be redimmed for each element).

Comment: You could, but then you have a mess that can't be passed as a parameter, received as a return value, stored in a Collection, etc. without creating a separate DLL to define it in.

Comment: why not? i probably dont understand you as yuo seem way more experience than me :) but i often pass an udt as argument and as return values. i never used them in collections though, so not sure about that. you define to define the udt in the right scope though. many api require special udt as well. i added another answer using udt to show what i mean

Answer (score 0):

another answer using udt with arrays inside it which can be redimmed

```
Option Explicit

Private Type MyUdt
  strOne() As String
  strTwo() As String
End Type

Private mudtGlobal As MyUdt

Private Sub Form_Click()
  Dim intIndex1 As Integer
  With mudtGlobal
    For intIndex1 = 0 To UBound(.strOne)
      .strOne(intIndex1) = CStr(intIndex1)
    Next intIndex1
  End With 'mudtGlobal
  PrintVals mudtGlobal
End Sub

Private Sub Form_DblClick()
  Dim udtLocal As MyUdt
  'using local udt which is filled with the return value of the function
  udtLocal = FacVals(udtLocal)
  'passing the local udt as an argument
  PrintVals udtLocal
  'passing the global udt as an argument to show the different values
  PrintVals mudtGlobal
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  With mudtGlobal
    ReDim .strOne(3) As String
    ReDim .strTwo(2, 5) As String
  End With 'mudtGlobal
End Sub

Private Sub PrintVals(udt2Print As MyUdt)
  Dim intIndex1 As Integer, intIndex2 As Integer
  Dim strPrint As String
  strPrint = ""
  With udt2Print
    strPrint = .strOne(0)
    For intIndex1 = 1 To UBound(.strOne)
      strPrint = strPrint & "," & .strOne(intIndex1)
    Next intIndex1
    strPrint = strPrint & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    For intIndex1 = 0 To UBound(.strTwo, 1)
      strPrint = strPrint & .strTwo(intIndex1, 0)
      For intIndex2 = 1 To UBound(.strTwo, 2)
        strPrint = strPrint & "," & .strTwo(intIndex1, intIndex2)
      Next intIndex2
      strPrint = strPrint & vbCrLf
    Next intIndex1
  End With 'udt2Print
  Print strPrint
End Sub

Private Function FacVals(udtArg As MyUdt) As MyUdt
  Dim intIndex1 As Integer, intIndex2 As Integer
  'copying values
  udtArg = mudtGlobal
  'redimming the local udt
  With udtArg
    ReDim Preserve .strOne(7)
    ReDim Preserve .strTwo(2, 9)
  End With 'udtArg
  With udtArg
    For intIndex1 = 0 To UBound(.strTwo, 1)
      For intIndex2 = 0 To UBound(.strTwo, 2)
        .strTwo(intIndex1, intIndex2) = CStr(intIndex1 * intIndex2)
      Next intIndex2
    Next intIndex1
  End With 'udtarg
  FacVals = udtArg
End Function
```

double click the form to see the result values

Comment: i forgot to create an array of the udt to make strOne and strTwo inner arrays, sorry

Comment: Very useful (+1), I'll play with this.